# Undefined index: submit in E:\xampp\htdocs\FA2\search.php on lin

Tags: php, mysql

> Undefined index: submit in E:\xampp\htdocs\FA2\search.php on line2

```
 <?php
 $button = $_GET [ 'submit' ];
  $search = $_GET [ 'search' ];
   if( !$button )
    echo "you didn't submit a keyword";
     else { 
     if( strlen( $search ) <= 1 )
      echo "Search term too short";
       else { 
       echo "You searched for <b> $search </b> <hr size='1' > </ br > ";
        mysql_connect( "localhost","root","") ;
         mysql_select_db("fa");
          $search_exploded = explode ( " ", $search );
           $x = 0;
            foreach( $search_exploded as $search_each ) {
                 $x++; 
                 $construct = ""; 
                 if( $x == 1 ) 
                 $construct .="keywords LIKE '%$search_each%'";
                  else $construct .="AND keywords LIKE '%$search_each%'";
                   }
                    $construct = " SELECT * FROM schoolname WHERE $construct ";
                     $run = mysql_query( $construct ); $foundnum = mysql_num_rows($run);
                      if ($foundnum == 0) 
                      echo "Sorry, there are no matching result for <b> $search </b>. </br> </br> 1. Try more general words. for example: If you want to search 'how to create a website' then use general keyword like 'create' 'website' </br> 2. Try different words with similar meaning </br> 3. Please check your spelling";
                       else { 
                       echo "$foundnum results found !<p>"; 

                       while( $runrows = mysql_fetch_assoc( $run ) ) { 
                       $title = $runrows ['title']; 
                       $desc = $runrows ['description']; 
                       $url = $runrows ['url']; 
                       echo "<a href='$url'> <b> $title </b> </a> <br> $desc <br> <a href='$url'> $url </a> <p>";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ?>
```

Form code:

```
<form action="search.php" method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input class="wow fadeInRight" data-wow-delay="0.5s" type="text" name="search" placeholder="Seach School Here" required/>
    <input class="wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-delay="0.5s" type="submit" value="GET STARTED" name="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: the form code is  <form action="search.php" method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <input class="wow fadeInRight" data-wow-delay="0.5s" type="text" name="search" placeholder="Seach School Here" required/>
     
      <input class="wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-delay="0.5s" type="submit" value="GET STARTED" name="submit"/>
    </form>

Comment: Have you tried to print  $_GET and checked is there any key named "submit"

Comment: no actually i want create a serarch page and which i want to search show in search.php page

Comment: You can't send multipart/form-data via get and the error message is quite clear by itself.

Comment: can you paste your url here

Comment: this time i do the work on local host and i change the method but the issue not resolves

Comment: Change line 1 from `<?php` to `<?php var_dump($_GET);` and post here the result

Comment: Doing this but the result is  Notice: Undefined index: submit in E:\xampp\htdocs\FA2\search.php on line 2
NULL 
Notice: Undefined index: search in E:\xampp\htdocs\FA2\search.php on line 3
NULL you didn't submit a keyword

Comment: if anybody want to take my system in teamviewer then please

Comment: There should be some kind of `array(3) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> int(2) [2]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(1) "a" [1]=> string(1) "b" [2]=> string(1) "c" } }`  before these warnings

Comment: post the tw creditals

Comment: remove the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` from the <form> tag

Comment: 121 569 318 is my id

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82915/discussion-between-artur99-and-abhishek-shulka).

Comment: how did u get those upvotes? seems fake

Answer (score 0):

When you do the get request it looks like the submit value is not set, this makes is null and you get that error.

Comment: how to fix the problem and how to set the submit the value

Comment: When you submit the for can you use post on the method and change the $_get to $_post?

Answer (score 0):

First check

> isset

:

```
    <?php
if(isset($_GET)){
 $button = $_GET [ 'submit' ];
  $search = $_GET [ 'search' ];
   if( !$button )
......
....
.....
}
```

Comment: The problem was on `$_GET['submit']`, so `if(isset($_GET['submit'], $_GET['search']))`

Comment: can you check `if(isset($_GET['submit']){`

Comment: yes, but with your code, he will get the same error, because the $_GET exists, and the next line asks for $_GET [ 'submit' ], that doesn't exist, so you will get `Undefined index: submit in E:\xampp\htdocs\FA2\search.php on line 3`

Comment: `var_dump($_GET)` inside of `if()` condition and show me the output

Comment: BTW :D I'm not the one who posted the question

Comment: i do all kind of things but the problem as same how i fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

As @Sami Kuhmonen said, the fault was `enctype="multipart/form-data"`...

This only works for `POST` data, because you can't send a file trough `GET`

So the form should be:

```
<form action="search.php" method="get">
    <input class="wow fadeInRight" data-wow-delay="0.5s" type="text" name="search" placeholder="Seach School Here" required/>
    <input class="wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-delay="0.5s" type="submit" value="GET STARTED" name="submit"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all remove those spaces

`$_GET['submit']` to `$_GET['submit']`

And instead use

`$_REQUEST['submit']`

It contains all parameters submitted via `GET` or `POST` method